# Cannot implicitly convert int? to complex type

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, ado.net, complextype

I have created a `Complex Types` i.e. **GetIsActive_Result** in `DemoModel.edmx`. It has one `Scalar Property`   i.e. **InvitationID** of type **Int32**. I have created one function which execute the store procedure. Here my function.

```
    public GetIsActive_Result GetIsActiveUser(string email)
    {
        GetIsActive_Result result = null;

        System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter InvitationID;
        InvitationID = new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("InvitationID", -1);

        var results = this.DataContext.GetIsActiveUser(email, InvitationID);
        if (results != null)
        {
            result = results.FirstOrDefault();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This function execute the store procedure i.e. **GetIsActiveUser**.

```
USE [Demo]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[GetIsActiveUser]
(
    @Email NCHAR(100),
    @InvitationID INT OUTPUT        
)
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRY

    IF EXISTS(select * from Users,Invitations where UserName=@Email and IsActive='Active' and Invitations.Email != @Email)
        BEGIN 
            SET @InvitationID=1
        END

    ELSE IF EXISTS(select * from Users,Invitations where UserName=@Email and IsActive='InActive' and  Invitations.Email = @Email)
        BEGIN 
            SET @InvitationID=0
        END

    SELECT @InvitationID AS InvitationID
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK
        END
    EXEC ThrowError
END CATCH
END
```

This is a simple store procedure which returns the **InvitationID**. I am getting the following error on line `result = results.FirstOrDefault();`

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'DemoAppWebService.GetIsActive_Result'

How can I solve this error? What was wrong with my code ?

Comment: Why (the complicated confusion of INT as a Complex Type) ?

Comment: Actually the Final Result will come to `ObjectParameter` `InvitationID` Rite?? whether it is out parameter??? or How the returning object from the function `GetIsActiveUser` is constructed? However only Int is returning?????

Answer (score 3):

```
DataContext.GetIsActiveUser
```

is returning you a nullable int. and you are trying to parse it into `DemoAppWebService.GetIsActive_Result` which is not allowed. You need to change your method like the one below

OR if you want your existing code (with slight modification) to work than your method `DataContext.GetIsActiveUser` needs to return `DemoAppWebService.GetIsActive_Result`

```
public int? GetIsActiveUser(string email)
{
    System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter InvitationID;
    InvitationID = new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("InvitationID", -1);

    return this.DataContext.GetIsActiveUser(email, InvitationID);
}
```

Comment: I have already set the Nullable property of InvitationID in GetIsActiveUser

Comment: the problem is that your method DataContext.GetIsActiveUser(email, InvitationID); is returning an int? not DemoAppWebService.GetIsActive_Result

Comment: What the OP wants is some object of type `GetIsActive_Result` returned not `int?`.

Comment: @KingKing you might be right. updated the answer to tell OP what needs to be done if he wants that.

Comment: @Ajay You should provide the class definition of `GetIsActive_Result` so that we can help you initialize new instance of that class and return it accordingly instead of an `int?`. You may need a corresponding `SQL function` which returns such a complex type.

Comment: Hey guys I have given wrong written type in my Function Imports. Thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 1):

You May use linq

```
var results = this.DataContext.GetIsActiveUser(email, InvitationID)
.Cast<GetIsActive_Result>();
```

Caution Error / or Returns NULL if unable to Cast

OR you can Construct an object of `GetIsActive_Result` with the Nullable `int` Result.

Comment: I have already set the Nullable property of InvitationID in GetIsActiveUser

Comment: Hey I have given wrong written type in my Function Imports. Thanks a lot for help